# control four motors with Motor Driver 1A Dual TB6612FNG

Tags: arduino, motor, driver

I know I can control 2 brushed DC motors bidrectionally with the Motor Driver 1A Dual TB6612FNG, but can I somehow control 4 brushed DC motors with the Motor Driver 1A Dual TB6612FNG, **NOT BIDIRECTIONAL**? (I thought I might be able to because i don't need direction control, so I thought to connect each output to each motor and their ground to the chip ground and also send PWM signal to the direcion pin)

Would this work? (I don't have one to test it)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, approximately.  I wouldn't PWM the direction pin though, as that would likely toggle between two motors.

To drive a motor unidirectionally, you only need one switch, but to drive it bi-directionally you need 4, usually in an H-bridge configuration.  Low side switches tend to be N-type semiconductors which are more efficient than P-side, so you probably want to connect each of your motors between the supply and one of the switched output, and set the output high to disable the motor.

You'll have to pull the data sheet and work out the details of the control signals; you may find that you cannot run the motors with full independence.

You might also look at using N-type logic level gate MOSFETS alone, one per motor.  But selecting and applying those can be a bit more involved than just using a chip like the TB6612.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I asked this question after looking by myself on the datasheet and I couldn't figure out if this is possible or not, so I'd hope that the answers here would tell me exactly how to do this. (I'm a newbie)

Comment: It's definitely possible, the only question is if you will be able to do so with full independence between the motors.  If there is a direction input, rather than a distinct input for each half bridge, then the answer would be no - you could not energize both of each pair of motors at the exact same time.

Comment: As I said.. I don't know how to do it even without full independence, so I asked you how. (I want to be sure before I buy it)

Comment: You can do it without independence.  If you need independence, you'll have to spend more time reading the data sheet or risk a few dollars; I don't have time to dig it up and read it for you right now - but my suspicion is that this is *not* the chip you want if you need fully independent control such that you can run both motors of a pair at once.

Comment: Ok, got a suggestion for a board to control 4 motors, direction control is not important, the operate on 3-5v and specification says that no-load with 3v is 22mA? Thanks :-)

Comment: oh and speed control is important! (and I meant "they oparate" not "the oparate")

Comment: IIRC 3v is a bit low a supply voltage for the TB6612, though it will probably accept that on the control inputs.

Comment: That is why I asked for suggestion for other speed controllers :)